# MarkLogic: how to search for an XPath using cts:uris

Tags: xpath, marklogic, cts-search

Is it possible to search for a uri whose document contains a certain XPath using `cts:uris()`? I thought it may be quicker than returning uris from a `cts:search`. Here is what I have currently:

```
declare function local:xpath-search($collection)  {
 for $i in cts:search(//a/b, cts:and-query((cts:collection-query($collection)) ))[1] return fn:base-uri($i) 
} ;
```

Is there a quicker way to return documents that contain a match to the XPath `//a/b`, using `cts:uris()`?

Comment: You could eliminate the FLWOR and just use: `cts:search(//a/b, cts:and-query((cts:collection-query($collection) )) )/fn:base-uri() `

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cts:element-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query) to construct a cts:query that functions similar to the XPath expression `//a/b` searching for documents that have `a` elements that have `b` element descendants. It isn't exactly the same, and might give you some false positives, because it is really more akin to `//a//b`, but might be acceptable and can be used with `cts:uris()`.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:xpath-search($collection)  {
  cts:uris("", (), 
    cts:and-query(( 
      cts:collection-query($collection),
      cts:element-query(xs:QName("a"), 
        cts:element-query(xs:QName("b"), cts:and-query(()) ) ) )) )
};
```

Comment: If you are willing to create a path range index, you can use that in the same way in replacement of the nested cts:element-queries, but needing those path indexes makes that a less flexible approach..